# Foundation Tooltip data-allow-html not working

Tags: tooltip, zurb-foundation

I need tooltips in Foundation to accept html. The html in the title tag is not being read as html. Here is a simple example: https://sc.imaginalmarketing.net/test/

Here's the code:

```
<h3 data-tooltip data-allow-html="true" class="has-tip" title="<p>This is the description</p>">This is a tooltip</h3>
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure how to do it directly, but you can use javascript to adjust it. I did this in the console in Google's inspector (with code cobbled together from other places):

Select the tooltip by role (assuming you only have one tooltip on the page):

`tooltip = document.querySelectorAll('[role="tooltip"]')[0]`

Create the html element you want to append:

```
var a = document.createElement('a');
var linkText = document.createTextNode("my title text");
a.appendChild(linkText);
a.title = "my title text";
a.href = "http://example.com";
document.body.appendChild(a);
```

Append the html element to the tooltip:

`tooltip.appendChild(a)`

Hope that helps!